# Data structure to multi-sort feature vector by attributes

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort a vector with tuples

[
  (a_<sub>11</sub>, ..., a_<sub>1n</sub>), 
    ... , 
  (a_<sub>m1</sub>, ..., a_<sub>mn</sub>)
]

based on a list of attributes and their comparison operators < or >.
For example: sort first by a_<sub>2</sub> with the > operator and by a_<sub>57</sub> with the < operator.

**Question**: I am looking for a data structure to do this efficiently under the assumption that sorting happens much more often than updates to the vector.

---

My current idea is to store the sorting order for each attribute by adding pointers similar to a linked list for each attribute:

For example, this vector:

```
0: (1, 7, 4)
1: (2, 5, 6)
2: (3, 4, 5)
```

Would get the data structure

```
0: (1 next:1 prev:-, 7 next:- prev:1, 4 next:2 prev:-)
1: (2 next:2 prev:1, 5 next:0 prev:2, 6 next:- prev:2)
2: (3 next:- prev:2, 4 next:1 prev:-, 5 next:1 prev:0)
```

---

Edit:

- At any given time I need only one sorting order. After I get a user request for a different sorting order I need to recompute as quickly as possible.
- The incremental idea is very good, but I need to make an estimate on how much time I need and this is way more easy if I have an idea how it should be done.
- Once i am finished I need random access to groups of 100 elements, i.e. the first 100, the second 100, or elements 5100-5199.

Comment: What interface do you need for the sorted tuples? Random-access iterator / lookup? Forward iterator? Whole sequence as vector? Maximum or minimum element? I'd start with defining this interface and then start to worry about how to implement this interface most easily. Later, after profiling, I'd consider adding hacks to make this even faster, e.g. by creating and caching an index for the various sorting orders.

Comment: Do you need multiple sort orders to be available at the same time? Storing indices per each sorting could make things a bit easier.

Comment: I would use boost::MultiIndex for this.

Comment: @MarcoA. can you add more info, I don't get it.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, this is a good solution. If you post this as answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use boost::MultiIndex for this. –  drescherjm

Comment: @AmiTavory It solves my question, therefore it can be relevant to others and comments can vanish any time. I don't know why he did not post as answer.

Comment: I did not post this as an answer for two reasons. After rereading the question I was unsure that this would be the best solution for your problem (unsure how second and subsequent level sorts would work dynamically) also as a person who reviews answers frequently I would normally want answers to have an explanation to answer the question how to use boost::MultiIndex. Since I did not have time for the how part I declined..